# Apache Camel: Aggregator with completionTimeout AND completionSize?

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregation

I'm using the Apache Camel java DSL `aggregator`, and I want both `completionTimeout` AND `completionSize` to play nice together (whichever triggers first should complete the aggregation).

```
.from("direct:aggregateResponses")
    .aggregate(property(KEY), new KeepSuccessfulAggregationStrategy())
    .completionTimeout(500)
    .completionSize(property(NUMBER_RESPONSES_TO_EXPECT))
```

I am sending requests to 2 web services and aggregating 2 responses ("Scatter Gather" pattern).

First example, if both responses are returned within 100ms (and `NUMBER_RESPONSES_TO_EXPECT` == 2), the aggregator returns a result (and does not wait 500ms) *This is working as intended.*

Now, second case, let's say the first response returns after 100ms and the second response takes 3000ms (I can test this via mocks in a test route...)

I would like the aggregator to "stop" after 500ms, returning me the first response and discarding the second. Yet, **the completion timeout is not triggering** whilst number of responses < `NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES_TO_EXPECT`.

What is the easiest way to get this to work?

I.e. I want to combine both of these, which work independently:

```
.from("direct:aggregateResponses")
    .aggregate(property(KEY), new KeepSuccessfulAggregationStrategy())
    .completionTimeout(500)
```

and

```
.from("direct:aggregateResponses")
    .aggregate(property(KEY), new KeepSuccessfulAggregationStrategy())
    .completionSize(property(NUMBER_RESPONSES_TO_EXPECT))
```

Thanks, Steve. (Camel version = 2.10)

Comment: Update: this seems like a bug / issue in camel 2.10, since it works successfully in camel 2.12. Unfortunately, my app runs in Fuse ESB container and it would be a big job to upgrade to a newer camel version. Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you have a subscription then use the customer portal to ask for a fix. If not you are on your own to patch / find a workaround

Comment: Okay. Since camel `2.10.0.fuse-71-047` is bundled with Fuse ESB 7.1, it seems we need to consider upgrading to Fuse Fabric 6.1 / Fabric8 (which is shipped with camel `2.12`).

Comment: Note that when the timeout completes, it does so from a different thread. May or may not be important.